# How to make the browser back button disregard hash tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have a website that uses hashes to open/close some tabs and layers on the current page. The reason behind using hashes is, that if a user visits another page via a link and then goes back to the original page all tabs and layers should open up exactly as they were when leaving that page.

The problem is, that while being on the first page and using the browser back button, only the hashes change and the user must click multiple times to actually go back to the last 'real' page.

---

Can that behaviour be changed? Here's an example workflow:

So I am visiting a page:

`start.php` > click link > `processing.php` > click tab, hash changes >

`processing.php#1` > click a different section on the page, hash changes to >

`processing.php#1-2`

Now when I hit the browser back button I want to go back to:

`start.php` NOT `processing.php#1`

---

BUT! When I go from:

`processing.php#1-2` > navigate to > `otherpage.php`

and then hit the back button from there, I need to go back to:

```
processing.php#1-2
```

in order to restore the open tabs and layers.

Is that possible!? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. It might be possible to do some hacky hash manipulation code where you store the history as the hash changes and when the browser goes back, it fires an event to keep going back until it exits the page. That's probably more work than it's worth.

Comment: I would suggest simply running your JS events without generating new hash tags, since you clearly no longer have any use for them.

Comment: i do. i need them going from example.php#1 to other_page.php and then going back to example.php#1 <- that's where i need the hashes

Comment: Look into the history methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, you *can’t* solve this without JavaScript. The fragment is part of the URL, and when it changes, the new URL is added to history.

I would suggest using `location.replace()` when you want to change the URL without creating a history entry. Instead of setting `window.location.hash`, try this:

```
window.location.replace('#1');
```

I’ll leave it up to you to pick the best way to integrate this into your website, but here’s one minimally-tested option for catching clicks on links:

```
$(window).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
    if (href && href[0] === '#') {
        window.location.replace(e.target.href);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Use .replace() to modify the hash without creating history entries.

Comment: @Aknosis I thought that’s what I said… No?

Comment: I was just reiterating/summarizing what you said.

Answer (score 3):

That's intentional browser behavior, and is the proper use of hash tags.  As a result, I suggest considering whether the javascript that is using those hash tags is the problem, and to change it to a different storage method.  Effectively, you can just use a globally available javascript variable for that purpose, because no page reload will be happening so the variable will persist.

```
window.stage = 'start';

// Another stage
window.stage = 'onfire'
```

You'll still want to suppress the standard behavior from clicks for js elements, of course.

Alternatively, if you want the stages to be stored, but not "navigatable", you can consider using localstorage on more modern browsers.

### EDIT: (based on the new information)

The thing that you are trying to do is an extremely common scenario in webdev because pages don't save much by way of their user's state/information.

You want to store information about what your users have completed, what stage they are at in a process.  Even when they have navigated away from a page.

There are somewhat limited number of places to "store" data: the hash, localStorage, cookies, *or client-side*, and that's about it.  If I were a user of your page, I suspect that I would want my data stored regardless -how- I navigate through your app.

So I suggest considering a better location for storing the state of your webpage than the hash, which is generally designed for navigation.  If they're going to be logged in via php, just store it via php to the database.  If not, then store it to localStorage where available and fallback to cookies, or just use cookies.

Your end navigation may look as tangled as this: `start page` > `processing page` > `any other page` > `processing page` > `leave the site` > `return to processing page`

But each time they return to the processing page, their data will be there stored, in the state that they left it.

If you *must* use a hash for some reason, @Sidnicious's answer has a way that may skip the step of creating a history entry, so if you use that for all the stages except the one before you change pages, your history will look like this:  `start`>`processing.php`>`processing.php#final`>`otherpage.php` which may cut down the back button hits down to an acceptable level.

Comment: The problem is, that there is also an other_page.php. So after clicking a link from example.php#3 which takes you to other_page.php and going back to example.php the hash change DOES need to appear, so that all elements can be initialized via the hash in example.php#3. It's confusing... I know :(

Comment: Well, a lot of this depends on your spec, but using localStorage could solve that issue in modern browsers.  The point here is that when you need navigatability, you -should- change the hash, even if you use a local variable alongside for all those stages that you don't want to be navigatable.  If you are attempting to make example.php change state and -not return to it's previous state when someone navigates away from example.php and back-, then you should probably think about actually storing the data, e.g. in the database in php.  So, err, clarify the requirements more?  Better example?

Comment: A few things:  Your original post is rather unclear.  In the future, I suggest skipping the example scenario and describing your actual situation, it'll make people give you more apt suggestions for solutions.  Your clarifications of the workflow did not clear up -what you are trying to do- very well.  Even better would be posting !live examples/snippets of what you're currently doing, e.g. on jsfiddle.net .  I will edit my answer to try to more completely analyze and suggest a solution to the problem that you have as far as I can piece it together.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered with the same issue as the one you described. I agree with Ivan Ivković's idea. The following is my code and it works for my case. I'm new to JS, but hope it helps.

```
var counter = 0;
window.onhashchange = function() {
    window.history.replaceState({visited: ++counter}, "visited page", 

window.location.search+window.location.hash);
}

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event.state.visited && counter>event.state.visited) {
    counter -= 2;
    window.history.go(-1*event.state.visited);
    }
    else {
    counter = event.state.visited;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe prevent the default behavior and make the jump to the hash with javascript?

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  $("html,body").scrollTop($(this.hash)[0].offsetTop)
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many hashes you've clicked since you've loaded the page, then use that count with history.go( - countHashes) to go back to your page.