# jquery - significance of .hash in this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I borrowed someone's jquery function and adapted it for my own use, but I do not understand exactly how it works. Specifically the line `var content = this.hash.replace('/', '');`

Could someone please explain .hash in this context?
The full jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bsapaka/KjcnL/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tabs = $(".tabs-group li a");

    tabs.click(function () {
        var content = this.hash.replace('/', '');
        tabs.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#panel > div").hide();
        $(content).fadeIn(700);
        $(this).delay( 800 );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the way the following anchor tag is set up:

```
<li><a href="#/hnf">Health & Fitness</a>
```

The hash value is the part of the href attribute after and including the hashtag: #

In this case, the code stores the ID of the element to be shown when the anchor tag is clicked in the hash, then a few lines below, the value of the hash is used as a JQuery selector to show the specified element (note that the hashtag is also the ID selector in JQuery):

```
var content = this.hash.replace('/', ''); // returns '#hnf' for the <a> tag above
[...]
$(content).fadeIn(700); // '#hnf' is the ID of an image on your page to display
```

Beware though, because using hash navigation in this way may cause unexpected results when a user tries to use the back button. Hashtag navigation is usually used to create entries in a browser's history upon displaying new data without actually navigating to a different HTML page. You should research hash navigation further for ways to prevent some of the pitfalls. The following SO post may be a good place to start if you find the back button behavior is undesired:

[How to make the browser back button disregard hash tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747714/how-to-make-the-browser-back-button-disregard-hash-tags)

Answer (score 2):

That gets the part of the `href` after (and including) the `#`.

An `<a>` element has several such properties, like:

- `hash`
- `host`
- `href`
- `hostname`
- `pathname`
- `protocol`
- `search`

In that context, they're using the hash as an id to fetch another element. Because the `#` is present, it's a valid id selector.

Comment: it also returns the `#`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that hash is found on elements that contain an href attribute or property

the bolded text  is the hash.

http://www.example.com/page.html**#stuff**